# Is an algebraic set unique?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, algebraic-equations

Let $\vec x$ be coordinates in $\mathbb R^n$. Let there be an algebraic set, $X$, defined by \begin{align}
P_1(\vec x)&=0, \\
. \\
.\\
.\\
P_m(\vec x)&=0,
\end{align}
where $m<n$. Can $X$ be realised by another set of $m$ polynomial equations not related by overall scaling, or is the set of polynomial equations unique?

Comment: Well, $x = 0$ can be realised by "$x = 0$ and any other polynomial with no constant term", for example - that's not related by scaling.

Comment: There are lots of alterations one can make that doesn't affect the set. One can insert something like $P_1(x)+P_2(x)=0$ or indeed any linear combinations of the $P_j(x)$; one can replace the entire set of equations by $P_1(x)\cdots P_m(x)=0$; ....

Comment: @GregMartin Your first suggestion has the problem that there might be new solutions not in X. Your second suggestion has the problem that the polynomials are not simultaneously zero (so that won't preserve X).

Comment: @PatrickStevens Yes, but that other polynomial will have new solutions not in X.

Comment: @dennis You appear to think that your algebraic set is the *union* of the zeros of the polynomials. Per https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Algebraic_variety the usual definition is in fact the *intersection* of the zeros of the polynomials.

Comment: @PatrickStevens Yeah I was confused by your 'and'.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, there are cases where $X$ can be realized by other sets of equations. For instance, if all your polynomials are linear, then $X$ is a linear subspace. If you've done some linear algebra, you'll know that there are infinitely many ways to represent a subspace as a solution set of linear equations.